# Creating addin for studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in

I'm trying to create a simple c# addin for visual studio. I've been following the guidelines dotted around the net, and it says to put my main code in a routine called 'Exec'.

However, I cannot find this routine anywhere. I'm assuming there should be a stub for this.
All I have is a connect.cs, with Onconnection, OnDisconnection, OnAddinsUpdate, OnStartUpComplete, OnBeginShutDown.

All I want to do is open one form with a button.

Thank you guys.
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should have the exec method that looks like so:

public void Exec(string commandName, EnvDTE.vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
{
handled = //your method here for eg.
return;
}

As far as i remember correctly this method comes from some interface or abstract COM class that connection inherited but i'm not sure as i'm not on the VS2005/2008 ATM.

Try adding the method yourself.